# How do I :split a window if the window already has been :vsplit?

Tags: vim

Let's say you open two files through a vertical split..

```
vim -O 1 2
```

Now how would I split this window horizontally across both of the vertical windows? So this is what a `:vsplit` looks like:

```
-----------------
|       |       |
|       |       |
|       |       |
|       |       |
|       |       |
|       |       |
-----------------
```

I want the end result to look like

```
-----------------
|       |       |
|       |       |
|       |       |
-----------------
|               |
|               |
|               |
-----------------
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `:botright` command with `:split` like so:

```
:botright split filename3
```

For more like this, see `:help botright` and page up.

Comment: Should that be `:botright split filename3`, instead of `:bottom split filename3`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `vsplit filename` to open a new window and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> (uppercase J) to move it to the bottom.

Have a look at `usr_08.txt`. There's a lot more about this and plenty of examples...